# Experience Cloud external sharing model does not show Account's Contacts related list

Tags: sharing, experience-cloud

I am working in an Experience Cloud site that was set up by another contractor. The site includes a tabbed Organizational Details page with related lists is separate tabs. The external sharing defaults are Private for Account, and Controlled by Parent for Contacts.

Organizations are shared manually via code, and this appears to work correctly - a portal user has access to their Accounts, and the tab for a custom object, also set to Controlled by Parent, displays as expected. However the Contacts related list does not appear for the portal user at all. Not an empty list, just a brief glipse of "loading" ellipsis, then nothing.

The portal user has read access to contacts and all the fields in the list via a permission set.

When logged in as sys admin (for instance, while editing the site), the contacts tab is populated with the related list as expected. Both profiles are set to the same page layout for this account type.

I have unshared and reshared the parent organization to this portal user in hopes that it might sort matters out, but my results have not changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: `Organizations are shared manually via code` means you are doing exactly what? Using Apex Sharing?

Comment: I am creating AccountShare records with Apex code (the previous model was using Flows to do the same thing)

Comment: And sharing sets can't do the job you need without resorting to apex managed sharing?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm open to ideas. Community Users are trainers who are assigned via a custom object to work with various accounts, and need access to a (limited) set of contact info about the account and its child records including contacts. This approach shows Account data, no problem, and custom child data, no problem. It's just the contacts that are obscured.

Comment: I'm out of ideas here, maybe someone else in the community with more experience with apex managed sharing can help

Comment: I put in a ticket with Salesforce help and they arrived at the solution quite quickly - while the external partner profile had read access to all the Contact displayed fields, it did not have access to the AccountID for the contact, and was thus unable to access them.

Comment: please add this as an answer to help out the community

Answer (score 0):

I put in a ticket with Salesforce help and they arrived at the solution quite quickly - while the external partner profile had read access to all the Contact displayed fields, it did not have access to the AccountID for the contact, and was thus unable to access them.